# Copying dataframes through variables vs copying through variables for columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been playing with python and understanding the concept of copying a dataframe through the .copy function as opposed to just reassigning it to a variable.

Let's say we have the following data frame:
dfx:

```
   Name        Score1   Score2  Score3        Score4
0  Jack            10  Perfect      10       Perfect
1  Jill            10       10      10  Not Finished
2  Jane            20       10      10             5
3   Tom  Not Finished       15      10             5

dfx2 = dfx.drop("Score1",axis = 1)
```

dfx2:

```
   Name   Score2  Score3        Score4
0  Jack  Perfect      10       Perfect
1  Jill       10      10  Not Finished
2  Jane       10      10             5
3   Tom       15      10             5
```

running dfx again still returns the original dataframe

```
   Name        Score1   Score2  Score3        Score4
0  Jack            10  Perfect      10       Perfect
1  Jill            10       10      10  Not Finished
2  Jane            20       10      10             5
3   Tom  Not Finished       15      10             5
```

Shouldn't the reassignment cause the column "Score1" be dropped from the original dataset as well?

However, running the following:

```
dfx3 = dfx

dfx3

   Name        Score1   Score2  Score3        Score4
0  Jack            10  Perfect      10       Perfect
1  Jill            10       10      10  Not Finished
2  Jane            20       10      10             5
3   Tom  Not Finished       15      10             5

dfx3.loc[0,"Score4"] = "BAD"

dfx3

   Name        Score1   Score2  Score3        Score4
0  Jack            10  Perfect      10           BAD
1  Jill            10       10      10  Not Finished
2  Jane            20       10      10             5
3   Tom  Not Finished       15      10             5

dfx
   Name        Score1   Score2  Score3        Score4
0  Jack            10  Perfect      10           BAD
1  Jill            10       10      10  Not Finished
2  Jane            20       10      10             5
3   Tom  Not Finished       15      10             5
```

does cause the original dataset to be modified.

Any explanation why a column drop does not modify the original dataset but an element change does change the original? and seems like any change to a column name in an assigned dataset also modifies the original dataset.

Comment: `.drop()` explicitly returns a copy unless you set `inplace=True`. The other thing is a python question about how object references work more than a pandas question.

Comment: `dfx3 = dfx.copy()` will clear this problem. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748890/pandas-with-settingwithcopywarning/56749160#56749088)

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `dfx3` and `dfx` to one DataFrame, if you want to do manipulations on `dfx3`with columns similar to that `dfx`'s then you should make a copy of `dfx` on `dfx3` not reference them both to the same DataFrame.

```
dfx3 = dfx.copy()
```